# React - Jest test failing - TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library, jest-dom

I've a jest test that is failing on addition of a new component to the page. The test is about showing of an error alert once error occurs. Code works in local environment but fails during commit.

### Error Text:

> TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text:
> Student is unable to perform register/unregister activities.. This could be because
> the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can
> provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more
> flexible.

### Test:

```
jest.mock('react-query', () => ({
      ...jest.requireActual('react-query'),
      useMutation: jest.fn((_key, cb) => {
        cb();
    
        return { data: null };
 })
 }));
    
 const useMutation = useMutationHook as ReturnType<typeof jest.fn>;
    
    describe('StatusAlert', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        useMutation.mockReturnValue({});
      });
    
      afterEach(() => {
        jest.restoreAllMocks();
      });

    it('should show error', () => {
        useMutation.mockReturnValueOnce({
          isError: true
        });
    
        const { getByText } = render(
          <StudentRegister
            students={[studentStub, studentStub]}
            onSuccess={jest.fn()}
          />
        );
        expect(getByText(ErrorDict.ErrorRequest)).toBeInTheDocument();
      });
```

### StudentRegister:

Adding this component is causing the above mentioned error:

```
interface Props {
      selectedStudents: Array<Student>;
      onSuccessCallback: () => void;
    }
    
export const StudentSelectionBar: FC<Props> = ({
  selectedStudents,
  onSuccessCallback
}) => {
  const [isOpenDropCourseModal, setisOpenDropCourseModal] = 
      useState(false);
  const [studentIds, setStudentIds] = useState<string[]>([]);
  useEffect(() => {
        setStudentIds(selectedStudents.map((student) => 
      student.id));
  }, [selectedStudents]);

  const onToggleOpenDropCourseModal = useCallback(() => {
    setisOpenDropCourseModal(
      (state) => !state
    );
  }, []);

  
  const {
    isError: isDropCourseError,
    isSuccess: isDropCourseSuccess,
    isLoading: isDropCourseLoading,
    mutateAsync: DropCourseMutation,
    error: DropCourseError
  } = useMutation<void, ApiError>(
    () => dropCourse(selectedStudents.map((student) => 
       student.id)),
    {
      onSuccess() {
        onToggleOpenDropCourseModal();
        onSuccess();
      }
    }
  );

  return (
    <>
      <StatusAlert
        isError={isDropCourseError}
        isSuccess={isDropCourseSuccess}
        errorMessage={
          dropCourseError?.errorMessage || 
              ErrorMessages.FailedPostRequest
        }
        successMessage="Students successfully dropped from 
         course"
      />
      <StatusAlert
        isError={registerMutation.isError}
        isSuccess={registerMutation.isSuccess}
        errorMessage={
          registerMutation.error?.errorMessage ||
          ErrorDict.ErrorRequest
        }
        successMessage="Students successfully registered"
      />
      <StatusAlert
        isError={isError}
        isSuccess={isSuccess}
        errorMessage={
           error?.errorMessage ||
           ErrorDict.ErrorRequest
        }
        successMessage="Students successfully unregistered"
      />
      <Permissions scope={[DropCourseUsers]}>
        <LoadingButton
          color="error"
          variant="contained"
          onClick={onToggleDropCourseUserModal}
          className={styles['action-button']}
          loading={isDropCourseLoading}
          loadingPosition="center"
          disabled={registerMutation.isLoading || isLoading}
        >         
          drop Course
        </LoadingButton>
      </Permissions>
      <DropCourseModal
        isOpen={isOpenDropCourseModal}
        onCloseModal={onToggleOpenDropCourseModal}
        onArchiveUsers={DropCourseMutation}
        users={studentIds}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

### Update:

I've noticed that removing `useEffect()` hook from the component, makes it render correctly in the test. Its function is to update the state variable holding studentIds on every selection on the list.

Is there a way to mock following `useEffect` hook with dependency in the test?

```
const [studentIds, setStudentIds] = useState<string[]>([]);
useEffect(() => {
      setStudentIds(selectedStudents.map((student) => student.id));
}, [selectedStudents]);
```

Comment: You can use `screen.debug()` or `screen.logTestingPlaygroundURL()` in the test to see what is rendered: https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#debugging. It might helps you understand why the text is not there.

Comment: Show the code of the `StudentRegister` component. Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @slideshowp2 most of the code for `StudentRegister` is given in existing and new component. One of the difference between the new and existing components is that `onClick()`, new component opens a modal instead of simply a `mutate`. Does this behavior has to be mimicked in the test as well?

Comment: @colinD. Thanks for your reply. I've updated the question with further info. Any thoughts?

Comment: It's hard to tell, where is `selectedStudents` coming from? It only appears in the `useEffect`.

Comment: @colinD, it is coming from a parent component. I've updated code to reflect.